# jquery .slideUp acting strange when invoked more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

EDIT : would help if my  tags were closed...no improvement alas.

What I'm trying to build is relatively simple. A slot machine-like interface with "rolling" images that eventually will slow down and stop. I'm using jQuery's .slideUp() function to do so, and it works well when applied to a single panel. But when applied to a second or third, the animation start acting weird.

Try this demo to see what I mean : http://bit.ly/wtiq36

Anyone know what's going on? The technique I'm using to simulate the animation is pretty straightforward, I just pile all the images onto the other, and swap the highest z-index for the lowest z-index-1 to put it back at the end of the stack once the slideUp() is finished.

(p.s. I am aware this loops infinitely, that part is not done yet :))

Here's the important code (html & js), or just check the source on that link for everything.

HTML

```
<div class="panel one">
        <ul>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:2"><img src="images/img2.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:3"><img src="images/img3.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="panel two">
        <ul>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:2"><img src="images/img2.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:3"><img src="images/img3.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="panel three">
        <ul>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:2"><img src="images/img2.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="item" style="z-index:3"><img src="images/img3.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And JS

```
function testit(n){
    $(".panel."+n).each(function() {
        secondclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
        div = ("."+secondclass+" ul li")
        if(secondclass != "stats"){
            flip(div)
        }
    })
}
function flip(div){
    highest = gethighZ(div)[1]
    highest.slideUp(400,'linear',function(){
        lowestZ = getlowZ(div)[0]
        highest.css("z-index",lowestZ-1)
        highest.show()
        flip(div)
    })
}


//these 2 functions just return highest/lowest zindex divs
function gethighZ(div){
    var index = -999999999999
    var result = Array()
    $(div).each(function() {
        var current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10)
        if(current > index) {
            result[0] = current
            result[1] = $(this)
            index = current
        }

    });
    return result
}

function getlowZ(div){
    var index = 99999999999999
    var result = Array()
    $(div).each(function() {
        var current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10)
        if(current < index) {
            result[0] = current
            result[1] = $(this)
            index = current
        }

    });
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stop all animations before:

```
highest.stop().slideUp(400,'linear',function(){
    lowestZ = getlowZ(div)[0]
    highest.css("z-index",lowestZ-1)
    highest.show()
    flip(div)
})
```

Comment: same thing...no changes in behaviour